# Beautiful Soup find nested div

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

**I am trying to parse a webpage that looks like this with Python->Beautiful Soup**

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti6pS.png)

I need data from

```html
<div class="p-offer__price-new">199,99 ₽</div>
```

I tried this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
res = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "poffer__price-new"})
print(res)
```

But result is empty -- []

**How can I get this data?**
  Example of URL: https://edadeal.ru/moskva/offers/d71b75ff-bfee-4731-95ad-52a24ddea72e?from=%2F

Comment: `poffer` is not the same as `p-offer`

Comment: Thanks, but p-offer__price-new didn't changes the result

Comment: Are thise dom element available at time of running your parser? not injected by some js plugin per chance?

Comment: try to access the website when you disable JavaScript, if you still find what you need that means you can complete it through `requests`

Comment: dynamic page, use selenium or extract from API request

Comment: It would help if you gave the URL you were trying to access

Comment: @MartinEvans https://edadeal.ru/moskva/offers/d71b75ff-bfee-4731-95ad-52a24ddea72e?from=%2F

Comment: @Stuart, I received correct html code from Selenium and can find this data. But can't get data with help of Beautifil Soup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://edadeal.ru/moskva/offers/d71b75ff-bfee-4731-95ad-52a24ddea72e?from=%2F')

html = driver.page_source

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
res = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "p-offer__price-new"})   
print (res[0].text)  

driver.close()
```